# How to get rid of the m2e add dependency quick fixes in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Since recently, in Eclipse (e.g. version 2022-12), when I haven't imported a type yet, such as `List` in the following code:

```java
List<String> list = null;
```

I'm now getting a list of options provided by `m2e` (probably?) offering adding some dependency to the project in the Quick Fix list (`Ctrl+1` on Windows, not content assist, which is `Ctrl+Space`).

[image]

This is hardly ever what I want (probably only 0.01% of all cases). How can i remove these items from the suggested list of quick fixes?

Comment: I've never seen this, so I'm wondering what plugins you have installed. What do you have in the preferences _Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced_? By the way, your Eclipse is outdated. Please upgrade. ;)

Comment: @howlger: This is about quick fix, not content assist. Anyway, in that menu, I just have *"Java Proposals"* activated. Will try updating. Will try the upgrade, and check if a vanilla Eclipse also has the issue, or if some plugin introduces it. But the `m2` logo looks just like that of `org.eclipse.m2e.feature`

Comment: I see and can reproduce it in the current Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, it has been introduced in Eclipse 2022-12 with m2e 2.1: https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/commit/a743960dc0d4c2f826ac596fbc4c3c4fbebafe1d You might [ask for a preference to disable it or for a lower ranking here, best with a pull request](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues).

Comment: Strange, I guess they forgot to mark https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/879 as actually done.

Comment: @howlger: I think deactivating this should be an Eclipse platform feature, not a plugin feature.

Comment: Quick fixes are a JDT feature, not a platform feature. Note, in your example, importing `java.util.List` is the first proposal. Is that really what you hardly never want? Could you please explain what you want instead? Create your own type instead?

Comment: @howlger: Often, the m2 items are on top. And often, I want to create the type. But always, the visual overhead is bothering me. What I want is to never see these options, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Then show an example where it makes sense. I doubt that this example will convince others to make a change. What speaks against limiting the m2e proposals to, for example, 3? IMHO m2e is the right place for a pull request. Do you need help doing so?

Comment: Ctrl-1 to set the type of a local variable gets hijacked by a bunch of maven dependency proposals. Awful. Can't count the number of times I've accidentally added a spurious maven dependency in this situation. I should be able to just type Ctrl-1 and Enter in that situation.

Comment: @DaveMoten Then simply switch them off or rank the Maven dependency proposals lower: https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/pull/1409